# How to shown that the Tangent Bundle of a vector space is a Vector Bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, gt.geometric-topology

Hello,

I have the following question about the tangent bundle $T_M =
\bigcup_{p \in M} \{p\} \times T_p M$ defined on a manifold $M$ of class $C^r$
modeled on a normed space $X$. My problem is showing that the tangent bundle
also forms a vector bundle. I found the following definition of a vector
bundle

A vector bundle is a tuple $E, B, \pi, F, \mathcal{T}$ where $E, B$ are
topological spaces, \ $\pi : E \rightarrow B$ a continuous surjection, $F$ a
normed metric space, $\mathcal{T}$ is a family $\{U_i, \varphi_i \}_{i \in I}$
of homeomorphism $\varphi_i : U_i \times F \rightarrow \pi^{- 1} (U_i)$ with
$B = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ such that

- $\forall b \in B \succ \pi^{- 1} (\{b\})$ has the structure of a
  normed vectorspace
- $\forall i \in I$ we have $\forall x \in U_i$ and $\forall v \in F$
  that $\pi (\varphi_i (x, v)) = x$
- $\forall i \in I, x \in U_i$ the map $\varphi_i^{(x)} : F \rightarrow
    \pi^{- 1} (\{x\})$ defined by $\varphi_i^{(x)} (v) = \varphi_i (x, v)$ is a
  linear function between the vector spaces $F$ and $\pi^{- 1} (\{x\})$

We call

- $E$ the total space of the vector bundle
- $B$ the base space of the vector bundle
- $\pi$ is the projection map of the bundle
- $\mathcal{T}$ is called a trivialization and $(U_i, \varphi_i)$ is
  called a trivializing neighborhood.
  \end{itemize}

Now for the tangent bundle it is easy to see that $T_M$ is the total space and
$\pi : T_M \rightarrow M : (x, v) \rightarrow x$ is the projection, $M$ is the
base space and I think we can equate $F$ with $X$, but how do you go on in
finding a trivialization. I thought first about using the induced atlas on
$T_M$ (that makes the tangent bundle a differentiable manifold of class $C^{r
- 1}$ modelled on $X \times X$ but its mappings has not the correct format.

My problem with using the induced atlas as a trivialization is that it is of the form $\{U_i, \varphi_i \}_{i \in I}$ $\varphi_i : \pi^{- 1} (U_i) \rightarrow \varphi (U_i) \times X$ and using
$\varphi_i^{- 1} : \varphi (U_i) \times X \rightarrow \pi^{- 1} (U_i)$ I'm
almost there but I have still not found a homeomorphism of the form $U_i
\times X \rightarrow \pi^{- 1} (U_i)$. The book I'm reading is talking about a
tangent space and says it is \ vector bundle but does not define a vector
bundle at all, so I looke up the definition of a vector bundle and failed to

Maybe I'm missing on the definition of a vector bundle (most examples I found
on the internet are about finite dimensional spaces ).

Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot in advance

Marc Mertens

Comment: What is wrong with the induced atlas?


Comment: Are you working from Lang by any chance?

Comment: you're going to see better if the normed vector space is taken the fiber $F$  in your definition of vector bundle AND for the tangent bundle you use this type functions: $(x,v)\to(x,J(\varphi_j^{−1}\circ\varphi_i)(x)v)$ where $J$ is for jacobian and $v\in F=\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: The book I'm reading is Fundamental Concepts in Modern analysis by Hansen, I have seen some books from Lang but they are using a lot of Category theory that I at this moment does not know very well.

Comment: I think you need to consult at least a few more references. This is really basic standard stuff that is explained very carefully in many places. One book that should have this and that many have recommended on MathOverflow is John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. 

Comment: Marc, you should mention right at the top that you're interested in the infinite dimensional case.  For many people, a manifold is by definition finite dimensional.

Comment: You already have a homeomorphism between $\pi^{-1}(U)$  and $\varphi(U)\times X$ . And you have a homeomorphim between $U\times X$ and $\varphi(U)\times X$, it is just $\varphi\times id_X$. Compose them and you get a trivialization.


Comment: How do you define $T_p(M)$ if $M$ is modeled on arbitrary normed vector spaces and how is the norm on $T_p(M)$ defined?

Comment: I agree with Sergei's comment (2 above).  Martin also has a point: one normally needs complete normed vector spaces to be sure that the derivatives exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help here, I think that the suggestion from Sergei is the way to go, as for the comment of Martin, the book I'm reading is indeed using a normed space and not a Banach space. The tangent space TpM is then not a normed space but a topological vector space. Maybe I have misread something or the book is in error but I would like to know why completeness is needed for the existence of derivatives. As for the remark of Yang I'm actually a amateur (having studied physics a long time and taking up a interest in mathematics a long time ago, but I will look at the book he mentioned. 

Answer (score 2):

The fiber $F$ should be the vector space of tangent vectors to $M$ at $x$.
It sounds like everything else is clear to you except for the local trivializations.

Cover $M$ with coordinate patches. Suppose $x\in M$ and $x$ is contained in two coordinate patches $\mathcal{U}_1$ and $\mathcal{U}_2$ with coordinate functions $x^1, \dots, x^m$ and $y^1, \dots y^m$, respectively. Then over $\mathcal{U}_1$ the tangent space has the basis $\{\partial/\partial x^1, \dots \partial/\partial x^m\}$. Similarly, over $\mathcal{U}_2$ the tangent space has the basis $\{\partial/\partial y^1, \dots \partial/\partial y^m\}$. The transition function is then given by the Jacobian matrix $[\partial x^i/\partial y^j]\in GL(\mathbb{R}^m)$.

Comment: He is apparently interested in the case where $M$ is infinite dimensional, modeled on a normed space.

Comment: Ah, I see.
Is it MO protocol that I delete my answer?

Comment:   This is indeed the case, I found some texts about the finite dimensional case. BTW for the definition of a vector bundle I found also only the finite dimensional case so I extended this to the infinite case (hope my definition is correct)

Comment: Don't know what MO protocol is but I made a error in my comment